# Is Cory Wong's Watercolors giving a nod to The Safety Dance?

Tags: jazz, pop, funk

In Cory Wong's album Elevator Music for an Elevated Mood, the song Watercolors, the guitar lick at 0:43--0:52 (which repeats several more times as one of the themes) sounds very much like The Safety Dance from Men Without Hats. Is there any indication that this is Cory's nod to that song? Or is it just a coincidence / often repeated lick?